# Verilog Program Editor and Compiler

Tags: verilog

This semester, I have a Hardware course which requires the use of Verilog. I Googled for some free Verilog IDEs in which I can write Verilog programs and also compile and run them (I think the right word is "simulate", but forgive me, I'm still used to C!), but I didn't get anything.

Could you suggest some free software for Verilog program writing and simulation on Windows 7? My college provides some software called Xilinx in the college PCs, but I think that's not a free software. And they are not willing to provide it to us on our personal computers as well. So any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Also, I am a newbie to Verilog. If you know any great resources for beginners to master Verilog, at least to some extent, then please do share them here as well! Thanks!

Comment: Also, is there any trustworthy plugin for Verilog in Netbeans?

Comment: This is very similar to a previous question you may find the answers useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731010/free-verilog-simulator-compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are professional tool provider such as [Modelsim](http://model.com/) and [Aldec](http://www.aldec.com/) who provide something like an IDE - with features like:

- source code editor, and you can set breakpoints in it.
- running compilation process
- running simulation
- viewing waveforms and other outputs

For Eclipse, I was aware of nothing - then [RossRogers'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20712/ross-rogers) comment pointed me to [DVT Eclipse](http://www.dvteclipse.com/) - neither of us have used it though :)

Personally, I use Emacs, a makefile and then run the simulator "by hand"

Comment: [DVT Eclipse](http://www.dvteclipse.com) is a verilog/Specman/VHDL plugin for eclipse.  I've never used it myself..

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://iverilog.icarus.com It's a free simulator and synthesis tool. Any text editor will do. Many people like vi, but you also use something like sublime text.

EDIT:
If you want a complete IDE, there is [Xilinx WebPack](http://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/ise-design-suite/ise-webpack.htm). It includes a simulator. It is free (as in free beer) but limited compared to the complete Xilinx software. But more than enough to get you started. If your college is using the same software, you should probably try this.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I wanted to know whether there is a whole IDE, integrated with an editor, simulator and more, like Netbeans. From what I understand about iVerilog, its not a GUI like Netbeans to write and simulate hardware using Verilog. Do you happen to know any?

Comment: Hey Mackie! Thanks for the information. But after registering for Xilinx, it wants all my information - my mailing address, my phone number, my pincode. I'm not really comfortable giving these information to get a compiler. Is there any other software (completely free, with no need to create accounts and all of that)?

Comment: @Karthik I am not aware of more alternatives. But maybee you could use a copy that is licensed to your college. Just ask your instructor.