# Where can i download a free Version of verilogger pro on windows 7?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am following this book i bought called "digital design by morris mano" which says it requires me to use "Verilogger pro and synapticad" which is not free software. Anyone recommend me a free version similar to these two and which works on windows 7?

I am looking at ghdl and gtkwave but i heard it is very hard to install this on windows but easy on linux which i don't use.

I am also looking at xilinx but i think it doesnt have simulation. And also i think its a very big file (5gb)and might be bloated

Comment: This is similar to [verilog-program-editor-and-compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14768492/97073). You can also try examples out on line and simulate with [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/)

Comment: The free xilinx ise webpack does in fact have simulation capabilities.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Rehos... for Verilog Simulation there are various Verilog simulator are present like-

```
(1)Aldec's Active HDL(Student Version Available)
(2) Synapticad's Verilogger Extreame 
(3) Xilinx's Isim 
(4) Mentor Graphics's Modelsim (Student Version Available)
(5) Synopsys's VCS 
(6) Open source and free ware "Icarus Verilog" which is work well in Windows 7
```

here is the link I send you just click and install ......and for simulation I send you some tutorials so that you learn Verilog with Icarus later but firstly this is the link of Icarus simply click on .exe...........

[Icarus Verilog simulator gtkwave inbuilt](http://bleyer.org/icarus/)

Rehos you are wrong as I described above Xilinx too have a Great Simulator inbuilt  Name "ISim"......
 and for your 5GB problem of downloading ..........here is the link from which you can order Xilinx Web Pack CD without any invest to your home.....

[Xilinx Web pack order Free of cost but takes time(15-20 days)](http://www.xilinx.com/onlinestore/dvd_fulfillment_request.htm)

Comment: I wouldn't use isim - it's buggy, and clunky.